# Saved web pages shows Javascript errors

Tags: javascript, d3.js

There is this great web site: http://d3-generator.com/

I did a Save Web Page-Complete and it is on my desktop now.

When I run the saved version locally, everything looks like the online version of the site, I copy paste the same CSV and click on "Generate Chart" button,  but at this point this is the error I get:

[image]

This is really easy to reproduce, you just save that web-page and try to run it locally and you will get that error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I debugged the file and it says 
`“Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP."`

You need to actually run a webserver, and make the get request to a URI on that server something like `http://localhost/graph/creator.htm`, rather than making the get request to a file; e.g. `file:///C:/Users/myuser/Downloads/Creator.htm`

Not all time,everything will work when you save the site locally.Sometimes not all referenced used on the site will also be save that's why some portion of it will really not work.

On # 3 : **Source Code Editor** just click **Export HTML**

HTML Export Source:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<!-- Generated with d3-generator.com -->
<html>
  <head>
     <title>Bar Chart</title>
     <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="chart"></div>
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v2.min.js"></script>
    <script>
function renderChart() {

var data = d3.csv.parse(d3.select('#csv').text());
var valueLabelWidth = 40; // space reserved for value labels (right)
var barHeight = 20; // height of one bar
var barLabelWidth = 100; // space reserved for bar labels
var barLabelPadding = 5; // padding between bar and bar labels (left)
var gridLabelHeight = 18; // space reserved for gridline labels
var gridChartOffset = 3; // space between start of grid and first bar
var maxBarWidth = 420; // width of the bar with the max value

// data aggregation
var aggregatedData = d3.nest()
  .key(function(d) { return d['Average Life Expectancy']; })
  .rollup(function(d) {
    return {
      'value': d3.sum(d, function(e) { return parseFloat(e['Average Life Expectancy']); })
    };
  })
  .entries(data);

// accessor functions 
var barLabel = function(d) { return d.key; };
var barValue = function(d) { return d.values.value; };

// sorting
var sortedData = aggregatedData.sort(function(a, b) {
  return d3.ascending(barValue(a), barValue(b)); 
}); 

// scales
var yScale = d3.scale.ordinal().domain(d3.range(0, sortedData.length)).rangeBands([0, sortedData.length * barHeight]);
var y = function(d, i) { return yScale(i); };
var yText = function(d, i) { return y(d, i) + yScale.rangeBand() / 2; };
var x = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, d3.max(sortedData, barValue)]).range([0, maxBarWidth]);
// svg container element
var chart = d3.select('#chart').append("svg")
  .attr('width', maxBarWidth + barLabelWidth + valueLabelWidth)
  .attr('height', gridLabelHeight + gridChartOffset + sortedData.length * barHeight);
// grid line labels
var gridContainer = chart.append('g')
  .attr('transform', 'translate(' + barLabelWidth + ',' + gridLabelHeight + ')'); 
gridContainer.selectAll("text").data(x.ticks(10)).enter().append("text")
  .attr("x", x)
  .attr("dy", -3)
  .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
  .text(String);
// vertical grid lines
gridContainer.selectAll("line").data(x.ticks(10)).enter().append("line")
  .attr("x1", x)
  .attr("x2", x)
  .attr("y1", 0)
  .attr("y2", yScale.rangeExtent()[1] + gridChartOffset)
  .style("stroke", "#ccc");
// bar labels
var labelsContainer = chart.append('g')
  .attr('transform', 'translate(' + (barLabelWidth - barLabelPadding) + ',' + (gridLabelHeight + gridChartOffset) + ')'); 
labelsContainer.selectAll('text').data(sortedData).enter().append('text')
  .attr('y', yText)
  .attr('stroke', 'none')
  .attr('fill', 'black')
  .attr("dy", ".35em") // vertical-align: middle
  .attr('text-anchor', 'end')
  .text(barLabel);
// bars
var barsContainer = chart.append('g')
  .attr('transform', 'translate(' + barLabelWidth + ',' + (gridLabelHeight + gridChartOffset) + ')'); 
barsContainer.selectAll("rect").data(sortedData).enter().append("rect")
  .attr('y', y)
  .attr('height', yScale.rangeBand())
  .attr('width', function(d) { return x(barValue(d)); })
  .attr('stroke', 'white')
  .attr('fill', 'steelblue');
// bar value labels
barsContainer.selectAll("text").data(sortedData).enter().append("text")
  .attr("x", function(d) { return x(barValue(d)); })
  .attr("y", yText)
  .attr("dx", 3) // padding-left
  .attr("dy", ".35em") // vertical-align: middle
  .attr("text-anchor", "start") // text-align: right
  .attr("fill", "black")
  .attr("stroke", "none")
  .text(function(d) { return d3.round(barValue(d), 2); });
// start line
barsContainer.append("line")
  .attr("y1", -gridChartOffset)
  .attr("y2", yScale.rangeExtent()[1] + gridChartOffset)
  .style("stroke", "#000");

}
    </script>
    <script id="csv" type="text/csv">Name,Population (mill),Average Life Expectancy,Area (1000 sq mi),Continent
Canada,33.9,80.7,3854.085,America
US,308.3,78.2,3784.191,America
Germany,82.3,79.4,137.847,Europe
Russia,141.9,65.5,6601.668,Europe
Mexico,108.4,76.06,758.449,America
Brazil,193.3,71.99,3287.612,America
Spain,46.9,80.9,195.365,Europe
France,65.4,80.98,244.339,Europe
China,1339,73,3705.407,Asia
Australia,22.4,81.2,2969.907,Australia
UK,62,79.4,93.800,Europe
Italy,60.3,80.5,116.346,Europe
India,1184,64.7,1236.085,Asia
Japan,127.4,82.6,145.920,Asia
Iceland,0.3,81.8,40.000,Europe
Portugal,10.6,78.1,35.560,Europe
South Africa,50,49.3,471.445,Africa
Egypt,78.9,71.3,387.000,Africa
Sweden,9.3,80.9,170.410,Europe</script>
    <script>renderChart();</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Click copy to clip board ,paste it on your text editor then save it as html.

Open your Html file and the graph will be generated.

Best Regards

Comment: Thank you so much for looking into this, still I didn't fully understand what to do? I should copy-paste the source you provided and save at as an HTML? Under what name save it? Can you please explain the steps in a little more details. Thanks.

Comment: oh you mean just save this HTML and open it? well that's not what I am lookig for. I want that saved version of that web site to be functional so at run time I can play with its numbers and draw charts.

Comment: I debugged the file and it says “Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP."

You need to actually run a webserver, and make the get request to a URI on that server something like http://localhost/graph/creator.htm, rather than making the get request to a file; e.g. file:///C:/Users/myuser/Downloads/Creator.htm